# How compare label field of arrayList in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, arraylist

I have an arrayList:

```
public var exampleData:IList = new ArrayList([
            {title: 'data1', data:[
                {label:'IT', value: 50},
                {label:'Business', value: 46},
                {label:'Doctor', value: 64},
                {label:'Teacher', value: 85},
                {label:'Engineer', value: 98}
            ]} ,  
            {title: 'data2', data:[
                {label:'IT', value: 63},
                {label:'Businss', value: 46},
                {label:'Doctor', value: 38},
                {label:'Tea', value: 51},
                {label:'Enee', value: 24}
            ]} ,
            {title: 'data3', data:[
                {label:'IT', value: 37},
                {label:'Business', value: 58},
                {label:'Doctor', value: 48},
                {label:'Teacher', value: 14},
                {label:'Engineer', value: 28}
            ]}, ]);
```

I want compare label field of each array in arrayList. Default, compare same with first array (title:'data1'). Similar below result:

```
public var resultData:IList = new ArrayList([
            {title: 'data1', data:[
                {label:'IT', value: 50},
                {label:'Business', value: 46},
                {label:'Doctor', value: 64},
                {label:'Teacher', value: 85},
                {label:'Engineer', value: 98}
            ]} ,  
            {title: 'data3', data:[
                {label:'IT', value: 37},
                {label:'Business', value: 58},
                {label:'Doctor', value: 48},
                {label:'Teacher', value: 14},
                {label:'Engineer', value: 28}
            ]}, ]);
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do. Are you trying to remove arrays that don't follow the first array?

Comment: yes David, just follow the first array by label field

Comment: A side note before I get into this: you should change `resultData:IList = new ArrayList` to `resultData:IList = new IList`

Comment: i think no, can use `resultData:IList = new ArrayList`

Comment: You can use `new ArrayList`, but it's good practice to use `new IList`

Comment: ok, so if use `new IList`. You can answer for this question ?